# How to get the date in japanese format (2008年12月31日) in oracle sql

Tags: oracle, cjk

I have to get the date in japanese format (2008年12月31日) in oracle sql.

I tried 
select TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY-MON-DD', 'nls_date_language=''JAPANESE''')
FROM dual;
But i am getting, 2019-4月 -04 . I am not getting the year and day symbols.

Let me know if there is a way to achieve it in oracle sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try a format 'YYYY"年"MM"月"DD"日"'

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. If we use select 
TO_CHAR(trunc(sysdate), 'YYYY"年"MM"月"DD"日"')
FROM dual; , the output will have 0's in the month and date field for single digit values. for eg: 2019年04月05日. But, our requirement is not to have 0's. So , we used select TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'FM YYYY"年"MONDD"日"', 'nls_date_language=''JAPANESE''') FROM dual; to get  2019年4月5日.